# Knitr, RMarkdown: How to have Latex page break omitted in HTML Output

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I have an RMarkdown file that I want to publish to both HTML and PDF. I use a page break command, `\newpage`, in the file to insert a page break in the PDF output. However, in the HTML output, the `\newpage` shows up as part of the content.

How do I get knitr/pandoc to omit the `\newpage` from the HTML output?

I tried embedding the `\newpage` in an HTML comment, but then it had no effect in the PDF output.

Here is the Rmd file.

```
---
title: 'RMarkdown Test'
author: "Carl Parker"
date: "July 16, 2017"
output: 
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
--- 


# Page 1 #

\newpage

# Page 2 #


**--- END ---**
```

Here is the code that builds/renders.

```
library( "rmarkdown" )
library( "knitr" )

render( "test-1.rmd", output_format = "all" )


# --- END ---
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that a code execute only for pdf and not for html, you may use function `knitr::pandoc_to()` as follows. You can also use it to write some text only for html or for pdf:
*Be careful with `\`, it needs to be doubled `\\` when called in a `paste` or `cat` inside a R code.*

````
---
title: "RMarkdown Test"
author: "Carl Parker"
date: "July 16, 2017"
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
  pdf_document: default
--- 

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


# Page 1 #
<!-- use newpage for latex only -->
`r if(knitr:::pandoc_to() == "latex") {paste("\\newpage")}`

<!-- Specific text for html or pdf -->
`r ifelse(knitr:::pandoc_to() == "html", "Text in html output only", "Text in pdf output only")`

# Page 2 #


**--- END ---**
````